# Functions as types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have some functions:

```
export function function1<T extends SomeClass>(thing1: T, thing2: number = 1): T['prop'] {
  return doSomeThing(thing1, thing2);
}

export function function2<T extends SomeClass>(thing1: T, thing2: number = 1): T['prop'] {
  return doSomeThingElse(thing1, thing2);
}

export function function3<T extends SomeClass>(thing1: T, thing2: number = 1): T['prop'] {
  return doSomeOtherThing(thing1, thing2);
}
```

All of these functions have a common "type":

```
type myFuncType = <T extends SomeClass>(thing1: T, thing2: number) => T['prop'];
```

Instead of repeatedly typing the same function definition each time, ideally I'd like to do something this:

```
export function function1(): myFuncType {
   return doSomeThing(thing1, thing2);
}
```

But obviously this is wrong. Is there anyway to say function1, function2, function3 is of type "myFuncType" without explicitly defining all the parameter and return types each time?

Comment: Like `const function: myFuncType = (t1, t2) => doSomeThing(t1, t2);`?  If you could make this code a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) I'd be more confident about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign functions to variables of certain type:

```
type FunctionTemplate = <T extends SomeClass>(thing1: T, thing2?: number) => T['prop']

const function1: FunctionTemplate = (thing1, thing2 = 1) => {
  doStuff1(thing1, thing2)
}
// or
const function2: FunctionTemplate = function(thing1, thing2 = 1) {
  doStuff2(thing1, thing2)
}
```

Also you may create an object with these functions, but that may not be the most beautiful thing:

```
interface FunctionTemplate {
  <T extends SomeClass>(thing1: T, thing2?: number): T['prop']
}

const functions: Record<
  'function1' | 'function2',
  FunctionTemplate
> = {
  function1(thing1, thing2) {
    doStuff1(thing1, thing2)
  },
  function2(thing1, thing2) {
    doStuff2(thing1, thing2)
  },
}
```